# Android DBFlow, ManyToMany retrieval error

Tags: android, database, where-clause, dbflow

Question is very simple. I have a model:

```
@Table(database = AppSazakDBModel.class)
@ManyToMany(referencedTable = PageDeclaration.class)
public class Category extends BaseModel {

    @Column
    @PrimaryKey
    public int Id;

    @Column
    public String name;

    @Column
    public String bannerAddress;

    @Column
    public int minAppSazakVersion;

    private PageDeclaration[] pageDeclarations;

    public PageDeclaration[] getPageDeclarations(){
        if (pageDeclarations == null || pageDeclarations.length < 1){
            Category_PageDeclaration[] category_pageDeclarations = (Category_PageDeclaration[]) (new Select().from(Category_PageDeclaration.class).where(Category_PageDeclaration_Table.category_Id.eq(Id)).queryList().toArray());

            ArrayList<PageDeclaration> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Category_PageDeclaration category_pageDeclaration:category_pageDeclarations) {
                listToReturn.add(category_pageDeclaration.getPageDeclaration());
            }

            pageDeclarations = (PageDeclaration[])(listToReturn.toArray());
        }

        return pageDeclarations;
    }

    public Category setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public Category setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Category setPageDeclarations(PageDeclaration[] pageDeclarations) {
        this.pageDeclarations = pageDeclarations;
        return this;
    }

    public Category setBannerAddress(String bannerAddress) {
        this.bannerAddress = bannerAddress;
        return this;
    }

    public Category setMinAppSazakVersion(int minAppSazakVersion) {
        this.minAppSazakVersion = minAppSazakVersion;
        return this;
    }
}
```

and another model:

```
@Table(database = AppSazakDBModel.class)
@ManyToMany(referencedTable = Editor.class)
public class PageDeclaration extends BaseModel {
    @Column
    @PrimaryKey
    public int Id;

    private Editor[] editors;
    public Editor[] getEditors(){
        if (editors == null || editors.length < 1)
            editors = (Editor[])(new Select().from(Editor.class).where(PageDeclaration_Editor_Table.pageDeclaration_Id.eq(Id)).queryList().toArray());

        return editors;
    }

    @Column
    public String SampleImageAddress;

    @Column
    public String SampleVideoAddress;

    public PageDeclaration setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public PageDeclaration setEditors(Editor[] editors) {
        this.editors = editors;
        return this;
    }

    public PageDeclaration setSampleImageAddress(String sampleImageAddress) {
        SampleImageAddress = sampleImageAddress;
        return this;
    }

    public PageDeclaration setSampleVideoAddress(String sampleVideoAddress) {
        SampleVideoAddress = sampleVideoAddress;
        return this;
    }
}
```

and as you can see, the first one defines a many-to-many relation to the second one.

every thing seems OK. And when initializing i do something like this:

```
for (Category category: initCategories) {
                for (PageDeclaration pageDeclaration: category.getPageDeclarations()) {
                    for (Editor editor: pageDeclaration.getEditors()) {
                        editor.save();

                        PageDeclaration_Editor rel = new PageDeclaration_Editor();
                        rel.setEditor(editor);
                        rel.setPageDeclaration(pageDeclaration);
                        rel.save();
                    }
                    pageDeclaration.save();

                    Category_PageDeclaration rel = new Category_PageDeclaration();
                    rel.setCategory(category);
                    rel.setPageDeclaration(pageDeclaration);
                    rel.save();
                }
                category.save();
            }
```

So as we can see, i initiate the relations either currectly.

but when i want to retrieve data from the relation,

```
public PageDeclaration[] getPageDeclarations(){
            if (pageDeclarations == null || pageDeclarations.length < 1){
                Category_PageDeclaration[] category_pageDeclarations = (Category_PageDeclaration[]) (new Select().from(Category_PageDeclaration.class).where(Category_PageDeclaration_Table.category_Id.eq(Id)).queryList().toArray());

                ArrayList<PageDeclaration> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Category_PageDeclaration category_pageDeclaration:category_pageDeclarations) {
                    listToReturn.add(category_pageDeclaration.getPageDeclaration());
                }

                pageDeclarations = (PageDeclaration[])(listToReturn.toArray());
            }

            return pageDeclarations;
        }
```

I got irrelevant error!!! the error is this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.cclever.appsazak/ir.cclever.appsazak.PagesEditorActivity}: com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.InvalidDBConfiguration: Model object: ir.cclever.appsazak.data.model.Category is not registered with a Database. Did you forget an annotation?
```

But in the line,

```
Category_PageDeclaration[] category_pageDeclarations = (Category_PageDeclaration[]) (new Select().from(Category_PageDeclaration.class).where(Category_PageDeclaration_Table.category_Id.eq(Id)).queryList().toArray());
```

when i replace it with:

```
Category_PageDeclaration[] category_pageDeclarations = (Category_PageDeclaration[]) (new Select().from(Category_PageDeclaration.class).queryList().toArray());
```

every thing works fine, so i think the problem should be about the where clause.

I think DBFlow developers should improve the documentations about the many-to-many annotation!

any idea how to fix???

TG.